# Docker mysqld: Can't create/write to file (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)

Tags: mysql, docker-compose

When I run `docker-compose up --build database` I ma getting following error. I cannot make it work. How can I change `/var/lib/tmp/` permisions in docker container.

```
database_1  | mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/lib/tmp/iblofOgV' (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)
database_1  | 2021-05-31T15:21:28.270650Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to create temporary file; errno: 2
database_1  | 2021-05-31T15:21:28.270656Z 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error
database_1  | 2021-05-31T15:21:28.270660Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
database_1  | 2021-05-31T15:21:28.270663Z 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
database_1  | 2021-05-31T15:21:28.270666Z 0 [ERROR] Failed to initialize builtin plugins.
database_1  | 2021-05-31T15:21:28.270668Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Is there something wrong with the host PC?

Comment: Why is it trying to write to `/var/lib/tmp`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to enter docker container using bash or sh and then change the folder permissions. You can do it with this docker cli command:

```
docker exec -it [container_name] sh
```

or

```
docker exec -it [container_name] bash
```

If your image has bash installed (usually no).

Then just change the permissions to whatever you want and type `exit` to go back to the docker host.